# Can't display an image from a url

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to programming and my only experience is some very light C# and javascript.

I want to make a simple android app that will just display a picture and some data from the net however I'm having trouble just displaying an image(haven't tried anything else yet). I've searched SO and the web for code examples but can't get them to work.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my only Activity

```
package my.test;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/android.png");
    imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried other examples both using an AVD and my phone with the same result: blank screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why blank screen? Any logcat output or exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all that I can google and think of, I decided to try to use android version 2.1 to code for instead of the latest and what do you know it all magically works. I've tried the example in my question with success as well as one or two examples in the answers also with success. Thanks to all that helped and SO.

Though if someone can share an idea of why seemingly valid code works when I build for 2.1 and not 4.0.3 I'd be greatful. BTW tested on my phone which runs 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap FetchImage(URL url) {
    try {
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        return bm;
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Now you will just have to use the setImageBitmap method from ImageView to show the image.
Make sure you do Downloading part in AsyncTask.

**Below Snippet will help you**

**DownloadHelper.java**

```
public interface DownloadHelper
{
    public void OnSucess(Bitmap bitmap);
    public void OnFailure(String response);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class GalleryExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DownloadHelper downloadHelper = new DownloadHelper()
        {
            @Override
            public void OnSucess(Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void OnFailure(String response)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        new MyTask(this,downloadHelper).execute("image url");
    }
```

**MyTask.java**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object>
{
    private Context context;
    private DownloadHelper downloadHelper;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    public DownloadTask(Context context,DownloadHelper downloadHelper)
    {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        dialog.setMessage("Fetching Data!!");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null)
        {
            downloadHelper.OnSucess((Bitmap)result);
        } 
        else
        {
            downloadHelper.OnFailure("Error in Downloading Data!!");
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how to "Make sure you do Downloading part in AsyncTask." but ill google.

Answer (score 0):

can try

```
imgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/android.png"));
```

or if you need drwaable

http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet4724.htm

Comment: I think i may have run across that example but tried it just now and it's just a blank screen below "Hello World, TestActivity!"

Comment: are you able to open this file in your phone broswer? I want to check the network connectivity in phone ....

Comment: Yup just tried, typed the url in my phone browser and it loaded the image.

Answer (score 0):

Give the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in your manifest and check if your mobile is connected to net. You code works properly for me.

Comment: It is has always been there. Tried an AVD on laptop with a wired connection and on my phone with a wifi connection.

Answer (score -2):

Use WebView instead of ImageView like this:

```
html = "<html><img src=\"" + imageUrl
                        + "\"></html>";
final WebView webView = (WebView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
wvImageView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wvImageView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
This should display your image on WebView. If you want to provide zooming facility, try this:

webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

This should solve your problem :)

Comment: Looks like an overkill to display an image with a `WebView`.

Comment: Haven't tried this but is this viable? With my needs being only displaying an image with some sort of table(not sure yet) without any kind of user interaction, is "ok" and possible to construct like an index.html to load when the app starts?